# PHP one to many relations

Tags: php, mysql

I have to table posts and comments have a relation between them i want to display comments of post I display post but I don't know how to display it's commented PHP native help, please

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: sure i did that sire

Comment: @doloezz: Not even close. You don't show the schema of your tables, you didn't show the SQL or PHP you've tried, and your question is as clear as mud.

Answer (score 0):

I would be nice if you provide your table structures and the code you have so far. Without those information it is harder to help. ;)

I assume you store the post_id in your comments table? So after you fetch your post in your php-script you will execute a second query on the comments table having your post_id. Sth. like:

```
Select * From comments WHERE post_id = $postId
```

make sure that your $postId is safe against SQL injections. Fetch the results in an php array and test if it's empty. If the array isn't empty, you can loop through it with foreach and list the comments.

Answer (score 0):

**Your question is not clear, but here is a approx answer**

describe your table, displaying comments of a single post is quite easy,

```
SELECT * from comments WHERE post_id = 123
```

then use php to loop through comments

e.g

```
foreach($comments as $comment) { 
     ... 
}
```

OR if you want to get all posts with all comments, here is i created a fiddle for you

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0264e/1

Help yourself by editing the schema and playing with it

Comment: this solution i did it but it gives me  Warning: Illegal string offset 'comment' in

Comment: Well, I really write it as a general example, it does not mean it will work like that. You have to get results from a proper db connection and define comments before using it in loop. I hope you know how basic things works in php :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use left join to get this relation with post like 
example:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE Id=$postId LEFT JOIN `comments` WHERE id = post_id
```

where the post id field had put in the comments table.

I think this is best than use to separate query